# Jackson also needs getter methods to correctly serialize a bean property using @JsonCreator

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, jackson, spring-restcontroller

I am using Jackson to serialize some beans into JSON, inside an application that is using Spring Boot 1.5.

I noticed that to serialize a bean using the `@JsonCreator` correctly, I have to declare the getter method for each property, plus the `@JsonProperty` annotation.

```
public class Person {
    private final String name;
    private final int age;

    @JsonCreator
    public Person(@JsonProperty("name") String name, 
                  @JsonProperty("age") int age) {
       this.name = name;
       this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

If I remove methods `getName` and `getAge,` Jackson does not serialize the associated propertiy. Why does Jackson also need the getter methods?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Jackson uses reflection to access private and protected properties.
As soon as you delete the getter, Jackson doesn't know how to serialize/deserialize the properties (=your private fields).
The used `@JsonProperty` annotations of the constructor won't help Jackson to find the properties while compile time as your constructor will be used at runtime.

> Unintuitively, the getter also makes the private field deserializable as well – because once it has a getter, the field is considered a property.

Paraschiv, Eugen  - ["Jackson – Decide What Fields Get Serialized/Deserialized"](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not)

Comment: Is there a workaround around this limitation? I have some fields that I don't want to be exposed.